# How to insert data into two tables in mysql - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to insert data into two tables of mysql,

Tables are as follows:

1) t_entity_details
2) t_preferences

Columns inside the table are as follows:

**t_entity_details**

```
- Entity_id (primary key, auto-increment)
- First_Name
- Sex
- TagLine
- Personal_Desc
- DOB
- Lang
```

**t_preferences**

```
- Entity_id (primary key too, No auto-increment)
- other columns......
```

Now when I submit a form, the Entity_id should be same in both the tables. So how to do that?
Please help me with this.

Comment: are you saying one form input should go into two different tables? if yes can you  paste what you have done .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is simple. You can use "mysql_insert_id" to get the last incremented/inserted id. You can use that in turn to insert into your second table.

In Eloquent, things are even more simpler, Assuming you know about Eloquent Models,. You insert to the first table:

```
$insertArray = array('First_Name' => 'Some_value', 
    'Sex' => 'Some_value', 
    'TagLine' => 'Some_value', 
    'Personal_Desc' => 'Some_value', 
    'DOB' => 'Some_value', 
    'Lang' => 'Some_value');

$saveResult = EloquentModel::create($insertArray);
```

You can then get the last insert id as follows:

```
  $entity_id = $saveResult->id;
```

You use this to insert into the second table:

```
$insert_secondTable_array = array("Foo" => "bar");
$insert_secondTable_array['EntityId'] = $entity_id;
$result = SecondEloquentModel::create($insert_secondTable_array);
```

This inserts into both tables.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario do the query statement as,

insert into **t_entity_details** (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);

insert into **t_preferences** SELECT * FROM **t_entity_details**;

i believe this type will solve your problem if you don't do manipulation using other columns.